# can someone please explain what is a package and a dependancy and repository? and how they work?

Tags: kali-linux

as iam pretty new to kali linux, i've been coming across these packages and some other stuff. but honestly, i dont really know what are they and how they works. but i'm really interested to merge my brain in kali.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: You really should not be using Kali Linux if you are asking these types of questions. Kali Linux is not for beginners.

Answer (score 3):

A **package** is a specific collection of files, possibly including software.

A **dependency** is the relationship wherein one package *depends* on another, and will not function properly without it.  Most package managers will, when you request for a package to be installed which has unmet dependencies, automagically figure out which packages are needed to make the one you asked for work, and add them to the installation queue in the correct order.

A **repository** is a centralized collection of packages, which a package manager can be configured to use as its source for packages.

Comment: A package doesn’t even have to contain any files, but that’s nit-picking ;-).

Comment: I didn't want to get into metapackages since the OP was seeking a very basic level of understanding.  But yes.

Comment: thank you very much.. i just wanted to know the answer personally and not by reading on the internet. thank you

Comment: I have some bad news for you about where U&L is primarily found, friend.